# How can I return a array with React Components?

Tags: reactjs

If you want to see this project running you can see the codesandbox in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-drake-2ebb8p?file=/src/pages/landing/index.js).

I have a `Landing` component calling a `ReturnPokemon` component passing a string as props.

The `ReturnPokemon` component receives two arrays and sends back the array accordingly with the props it's receiving.

Now the `Landing` component has a console.log for the information that it is receiving from `ReturnPokemon`.

The problem with the code is `Landing` is not receiving the same array that `ReturnPokemon` receives, why is that? I need that `ReturnPokemon` send to `Landing` the same array it is receiving. How can I fix the code?

`Landing`:

```js
export const Landing = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Landing</h1>
      {console.log(<ReturnPokemon pokemon="ditto" />)}
    </>
  );
};
```

`ReturnPokemon`:

```js
import { useDitto } from "../../context/ditto";
import { useCharizard } from "../../context/charizard";
import { useState } from "react";

export const ReturnPokemon = ({ pokemon }) => {
  const [chosenPokemon, setChosenPokemon] = useState();
  const { ditto } = useDitto();
  const { charizard } = useCharizard();

  if (pokemon === "ditto") {
    setChosenPokemon(ditto);
    return { chosenPokemon };
  } else if (pokemon === "charizard") {
    setChosenPokemon(charizard);
    return { chosenPokemon };
  } else {
    return;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use a React component as if it were a [React hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

My suggestion would be to re-write as a React hook and then you should be able to correctly log the chosen pokemon:

**Landing Becomes:**

```
import { usePokemon } from "../../component/returnPokemon";

export const Landing = () => {
  const { chosenPokemon } = usePokemon("ditto");
  console.log(chosenPokemon);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Landing</h1>
      {chosenPokemon.name}
    </>
  );
};
```

**Instead write ReturnPokemon as a React Hook:**

```
import { useDitto } from "../../context/ditto";
import { useCharizard } from "../../context/charizard";

export function usePokemon(pokemon) {
  const { ditto } = useDitto();
  const { charizard } = useCharizard();

  if (pokemon === "ditto") {
    return { chosenPokemon: ditto };
  } else if (pokemon === "charizard") {
    return { chosenPokemon: charizard };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That is exactly what I was trying to do. I should had been using react hooks instead of react components.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use useState if you are going to return it anyway. You cannot return an object in a component. You have to return some JSX element like  and you can have your object inside.

Assumptions made here:

- ditto, charizard are strings. if not just do JSON.stringify(ditto) to cast object as string

Landing:

```
export const Landing = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Landing</h1>
      <ReturnPokemon pokemon="ditto" />
    </>
  );
};
```

ReturnPokemon:

```
import { useDitto } from "../../context/ditto";
import { useCharizard } from "../../context/charizard";

export const ReturnPokemon = ({ pokemon }) => {
  const { ditto } = useDitto();
  const { charizard } = useCharizard();

  if (pokemon === "ditto") {
    return <div>{ditto}</div>;
  }

  if (pokemon === "charizard") {
    return <div>{charizard}</div>;
  }

  return <div></div>;
};
```